# get jpeg image tags from file structure

Tags: java, image, file, jpeg, randomaccessfile

Hello my programmer friends :)

Do you know **file structure** of jpeg image file?
how can I get image tags from file like following image:

[image: image details window]

I want to get description of an image file with poorly java code in 2 way:

1. get image description with file and then by java `RandomAccessFile`,
2. get image description by java any way...

Comment: Google "jpeg file structure"

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi2z_rXqdjJAhWIW5QKHew0AjAQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FGraphics%2FJPEG%2Fjfif3.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEFUj0UeaE6eQqgCQ6STVGlispwfw&sig2=XMVKS1DWS7OIYE7zTjMX_w&bvm=bv.109910813,d.dGo) or [this](http://www.fileformat.info/format/jpeg/egff.htm) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format)

Comment: Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851665/java-library-for-reading-and-writing-iptc-metadata-to-jpeg-and-tiff) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224328/how-to-read-jpeg-file-attributes-with-java) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310162/imageio-get-image-type-and-exif-data) or [this](http://johnbokma.com/java/obtaining-image-metadata.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you face is that there are multiple JPEG file formats. Each format has different ways of representing meta data. You need to read the JPEG standard to figure out the structure of the JPEG stream so that you can identify APPn markers in the stream.

Then you need to examine the various JPEG file format standards to see how to parse the comments of the APPn markers.